# Xcode 8 screen broken when running on IOS 9

Tags: ios, xcode8

I ve just update to xcode 8. I have strange issue when trying to install ios 9 simulator (together with IOS 10 simulator). The only 1/4 screen is display. The rest is all black. Any one know what the error is any how we can make xcode 8 work with both IOS 9 and IOS 10 simulator? Thanks

[image]

[image]

Comment: Same problem, did you manage to solve it ? 
Simulator reset helps but if I do scaling or rotation the "blackness" come back.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you just try to reset you simulator once.

Comment: On left top, click on Simulator->Reset Content and Settings.

Comment: seem not working. I might have something wrong in my coding. Problem exist with my ipad application.

Comment: I thinks it's not because of coding. I can see you are on home screen and it's become small. Try to go in Window-> scale and try to set some scale, may help you?

Comment: Thanks windows scale working (previously at 50%). I make 100% an can see normal screen. But how can we reduce the preview size (100% too large) normally can press command +3 or Command +4 to adjust the preview windows

Comment: This is quite weird thing, if you reset to 33% it again shrink?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/124113/discussion-between-io-s-c-and-le-khanh-vinh).